# I was installing Jenkins and got this error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

When I tested the port this error popped.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbvfq.png)

I tried to install Jenkins and when I tried to test the port the error came please help me. This image is the error that popped on when i tried to install Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to give more context, are you running inside a container? or in your own machine?

In case of this is running on a machine, you can get this because the port is in use,  some other application is already using it, or no permission is guaranteed, (Firewall)

To discover what is happening,  you can get the port intended to be used here
jenkins.xml or jenkins.conf it will depend on your version and OS.

Explore the following options
-Try to change it and retry again,
-Try to run using admin su user
-Try to get what service is using the port.
ex Linux sudo netstat -tuln | grep [port]
ex Windows netstat -anb | find [port]

Hope that this helps!

Comment: I am running it in my own machine and can you explain in simple words